# how to make array of objects typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am attempting to make an array of objects using '.map()', but I get the error 'property name does not exist on type never', on both of the name properties within the .map().

Is using an interface correct, or should I use a type? Or do I need to somehow type check my .map values that are getting passed?

My code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "./Home.css";

interface HomeProps {
    extra: string
};

interface CountryInterface {
    label: string;
    value: string
};

export default function Home() {
    const api_url =  'https://restcountries.com/v3.1';
    const [data, setData] =  useState([]);


    function getCountries(extraUrl : HomeProps['extra']) {
        axios.get(api_url + extraUrl)
        .then((res) => {
            setData(res.data);
        })
        .catch(console.log);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getCountries('/independant?status=true')
    }, []);

    let countryArray: CountryInterface[];

    function makeCountryArray() {
        data.map((country) => countryArray.push({ label: country.name.common, value: country.name.common}));
    };
    makeCountryArray();

    return (
        <div>
            Home
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `const [data, setData] =  useState<CountryInterface[]>([]);`

Comment: @Konrad data has a different shape. Check the usage in the `map`:  `country.name.common`

Comment: Your `makeCountryArray` will not work. You should wait for you `getCountries` `Promise` to finish (to be resolved), then you should call it. Also instead of using `data.map(... push something)` use `data.forEach`.

Make your example working e.g. on https://codesandbox.io/, so we can fix this code for you with some explanation.

Comment: You're missing return in your like all of your callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not defining the type for the `data` state and just provide the initial value of `[]`, the compiler infers this as `never[]`. To solve it you need to include a type for the `data` state:

```
type CountryResponseItem = {
  name: {
    common: string;
  };
};
```

```
const Component = () => {
   const [data, setData] = useState<CountryResponseItem[]>([]);
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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-GUmIBEIWD7-YG9WMzWKwWhTvg-p5Ng1NNjtAB+dzSHg9RzlfCFuCydhcnlpEXjJqOKIAQSgTiirjr0TigX0rInfIFxxACAA1vRV-PFwgohcg3BowgIfuwD6Qc1K3Hp-TT0uIWAeOmOOksjkb7NBCgzDFCkzTOwJRlCMT6ziBQw5tCUyaAmrCusOfi2PuR4nguS4XBOKgwM8xzUuswBFGySo0n8FFUTUQA)